# Sorting an array makes pointers link wrongly

Tags: c++, pointers, shallow-copy

So I'm doing a sort algorithm of objects that have some integers and a pointer. Whenever I do the sort, the pointer starts acting odd and links to the wrong index.

Here's my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class person
{
public:
    int knots, time, ID;
    int untie, status = 1;
    person *next = NULL;
};
///DEBUG
void print(person *a, int p)
{

        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            cout<<a[i].ID<<": "<<a[i].knots<<" "<<a[i].time<<" "<<a[i].untie<<" "<<a[i].status<<" Next: "<<a[i].next->ID<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int p;
    scanf("%d\n", &p);
    while (p != -1)
    {
        person *people = new person[p];

        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            people[i].ID = i+1;
            scanf("%d ", &people[i].knots);
            if (i)
            {
                people[i-1].next = &people[i];
            }
        }
        people[p-1].next = &people[0];
            scanf("/n");
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d ", &people[i].time);
            if (i)
            {
                people[i-1].untie = people[i-1].time * people[i].knots;
            }
        }
        people[p-1].untie = people[p-1].time * people[0].knots;
        print(people, p);

        ///SORTING
        for (int i = 0; i < p-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < p; j++)
            {
                if (people[j].untie < people[i].untie)
                {

                    person x = people[j];
                    people[j] = people[i];
                    people[i] = x;

                }
            }
        }

        print(people, p);

        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            if (people[i].status)
            {
                if (people[i].next->untie == people[i].untie)
                {
                    people[i].next->status = 2;
                }
                else
                    people[i].next->status = 0;

                if (people[i].status == 2)
                    people[i].status = 0;
            }
        }

        print(people, p);
    }
}
```

The sorting is working fine, but the problem is when I'm linking "next" it's linking to the wrong object. The reason I'm using a linking is to maintain the order even after the sort.

Comment: This code is terribly convoluted. I'd throw it away and rethink everything from scratch.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: Also, why in the 21st century are you writing a bubble sort, when there's a perfectly good `std::sort()` available to you?  (Obviously that won't fix the problem of moving pointed-to objects, but it would make your code much, *much* clearer to read.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                person x = people[j];
                people[j] = people[i];
                people[i] = x;
```

This is because you swap the values in your sorting code above, while the address `person *next` recorded in the `struct` has not been changed.

Thus the old address is still inside the `struct person`, while the content in that address has already been modified during swapping, which leads the inconsistency.

Comment: What edit do you suggest?

Comment: @thethiny Let `vector` store pointers, instead of objects themselves.

Comment: Is my problem somehow related to shallow-copy?

Comment: @thethiny You seem to be attempting to combine the behaviour of an array with a linked list. What do you need the next pointer for?

Comment: @thethiny Not that related, the key point is the difference between the address of the object and the object itself. They won't be automatically updated to keep consistency.

Comment: @user4581301 So that I maintain the original order after sorting.

Comment: @thethiny You can go all-in on on pointers as liliscent suggests, you can make a copy of the array before sorting it, you can store the original array index instead of the next pointer. Each has advantages and disadvantages. All in on pointers has poor spatial locality leading to a greatly increased likelihood of cache misses (slows runtime performance), plus it picks up additional memory management concerns. Copy takes time to copy and doubles the memory cost. Recreating the original order from Stored indices can be expensive (but often not as expensive as a cache miss)